# Android: WRAP_CONTENT not working with layout_toStartOf

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a TextView in the middle and a TextView in the left. I want the left TextView always be `WRAP_CONTENT` and not overlap with the middle TextView. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_middle"
        android:background="#55ff0000"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/menuRedColor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="This is Title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is the left TextView always takes all the space int the left, not `WRAP_CONTENT`. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

If I remove the `layout_toStartOf` attr in the left TextView, `WRAP_CONTENT` will work fine but the two TextViews will overlap if the middle TextView's content grows long.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: remove this `android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_middle` and add this line to `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_left` in tv_middle text.

Comment: Remove center_Horizontal=true from middle textview.

Comment: but he needs the title text view to be in center horizontal

Comment: i think its better to try linear layout and apply weight attributes on views

Comment: OK then remove android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_middle" from tv_left

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you face any issues @hanswim

Comment: @HemantParmar but I also want the middle TextView to be in center.

Comment: @AIK If I remove android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_middle" from tv_left, the two TextViews will overlap if content grows long.

Comment: can tv_left content grow because i see only back written on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only `android:layout_toEndOf` and `android:layout_toRightOf` properties inside `Text View tv_middle` and give `id` of *tv_left*. Also remove `android:singleLine="true"` this is now `deprecated` instead of use `android:maxLines="1"`.

Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="#55ff0000"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat"
        tools:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_left"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="This is Title This is Title This is Title This is Title This is Title This is Title This is Title This is Title This is Title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will not overlap your `text` with each other and it will allow your `tv_left Text View` to always stay `Wrap Content`.

Output

[image]

Comment: This way the left TextView is just as big as needed, but the middle TextView("This is Title") is not in center horizontal.

Comment: @hanswim Middle *Text View* is in *layout_centerHorizontal* already as you can see *tv_middle* the property is already applied you can see  inside screen shot also.

Answer (score 0):

tv_left

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_middle"
```

Because 2 this feature so a length length from the left of parent to `tv_middle`. You must remove one in this feature 2 for `textview` may be `wrap_content`. 
Sorry, my English is bad

Answer (score 0):

I have update your code check here,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_middle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:text="This is Title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_middle"
    android:background="#55ff0000"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/menuRedColor"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="Back" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

after setting your text view to start of another textview, set the width of the text view to match_parent. It will not overlap with the center one.

Comment: This way the left TextView is also taking all the space before center TextView, Just as my screenshot. I want the left TextView just as big as needed.

Comment: then set the width to wrap_content. this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_middle"
```

to

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tv_middle"
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope it will work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:weightSum="2">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.30"
    android:background="#55ff0000"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="Back" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_middle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.70"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#222222"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:text="This is Title" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This way the middle TextView is not in center horizontal because the left TextView already takes some space.